# Polymorphic comments: can't pass type and id (NoMethodError for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to create polymorphic comments for `Question` and `Answer`, but `commentable_type` and `commentable_id` never get passed when I hit the "create" button on the "create comment" form. I can successfully create a new comment through the rails console, but not through the form (currently I'm testing comments for questions). I'm getting errors in `load_commentable` or `create` of comments_controller, like:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:9:in `create'
```

Seems that `@commentable` is `nil` (because it doesn't get `commentable_type` and `commentable_id` params?). 
What am I missing out?

migration for comments:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.text :body, null:false
      t.references :commentable, polymorphic: true, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
      add_index :comments, [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :comments, only: [:create]

  resources :votes, only: [:create] do
    delete :reset, on: :collection
  end

  resources :attachments, only: :destroy

  devise_for :users

  resources :questions do
    resources :comments, only: :create, defaults: { commentable: 'questions' }
    resources :answers, shallow: true do
      resources :comments, only: :create, defaults: { commentable: 'answers' }
      patch :set_best, on: :member
    end
  end

  root to: "questions#index"

  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
end
```

comments form partial _comment_form.html.slim:

```
    h4 Add a comment
    .comment_errors
    = form_for [@commentable, Comment.new], remote: true do |f|
      .form-group
        = f.label :body, 'Comment'
        = f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control'
      p= f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

comments_controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :load_commentable, only: [:create]

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.create(comment_params.merge(user: current_user))
  end

  private

  def load_commentable
    if params[:comment][:commentable_type] == 'Answer'
      @commentable = Answer.find(params[:comment][:commentable_id])
      gon.answer_id = @commentable.id
    elsif params[:comment][:commentable_type] == 'Question'
      gon.answer_id = @commentable.id
      @commentable = Question.find(params[:comment][:commentable_id])
    end
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :commentable_type, :commentable_id )
  end
end
```

comments section in question's show view:

```
h3 Comments
.question_comments id="comments_section_question_#{@question.id}"
  - if user_signed_in?
    .row
      = render 'comments/comment_form', commentable: @question
```

error log:

```
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in `create'
Started POST "/comments" for 10.0.2.2 at 2017-11-20 20:54:42 +0000
Cannot render console from 10.0.2.2! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"body"=>"kkkk"}, "commit"=>"Create"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 41], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

Comment: Check out your `params`: `"comment"=>{"body"=>"kkkk"}`. See anything missing? Then look at your form. You have `@commentable`, but where are you adding its values to the form?

Comment: id, user_id, commentable_type and commentable_id params are missing, but I don't understand why and how do I fix this

Comment: Google for `hidden_field`... BTW, I don't know what `id` refers to. But I imagine you wouldn't need `user_id` since you have that available via devise (something like `current_user.id`, I think. But, I don't use devise, so that may not be exactly right).

Comment: id is comment's id. I previously tried hidden fields, but this didn't work and gave similar error, I also read that the better solution would be pass these fields dynamically in the controller, but failed to fix the code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that your `partial_comment_form.html.slim` should be something like:

```
h4 Add a comment
.comment_errors
= form_for [@commentable, Comment.new], remote: true do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.label :body, 'Comment'
    = f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control'
    = hidden_field_tag 'commentable[id]', @commentable.id
    = hidden_field_tag 'commentable[type]', @commentable.class.name
  p= f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

Which should give you params something like:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"body"=>"kkkk"}, "commentable"=>{"id"=>"1", "type"=>"Question"}, commit"=>"Create"}
```

Then, you change `load_commentable` to something like:

```
def load_commentable
  @commentable = commentable_params[:type].constantize.find_by(id: commentable_params[:id])
  gon.answer_id = @commentable.id
end
```

(BTW, gon.answer_id when you have a Question seems odd. But, I don't know...)

Which, naturally, requires something like:

```
def commentable_params
  param.require(:commentable).permit(:id, :type)
end
```